# What could be the reason for this difference?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

What could be the reason for the difference in accuracies?

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)

ans = []

for i in y_pred:

    ans.append(0 if i[0]<0.5 else 1)

ans = np.array(ans)

print("Accuracy:",metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, ans))

Accuracy: 0.7781798160210841
```

While

```
print("Accuracy:",metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred))

Accuracy: 0.8949947592358702
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVdNp.png)

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `deep-learning` or `artificial-intelligence` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1):

ROC score **is not** accuracy. It is an area under the curve, that emerges when you construct your predcition by varying a threshold. In your code you removed the notion of "uncertainty", by outputing only 0s and 1s, and thus the ROC curve became flat - there is no threshold that affects your predictions.